# Rails: Authlogic & User Sessions & Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, authlogic

I want to call a service to find location data every time the `current_login_ip` on a user changes.

Now, one way to implement this would be to do

```
class User
#...
    after_save :kickoff_job_to_find_location, if: :current_login_ip_changed?
end
```

However, I'd quite like to avoid adding an ActiveRecord callback if I can.

So, I went down the route of customizing UserSession with something like this:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  before_create :set_update_location

  def should_update_location?
    @should_update_location
  end

  private

  def set_update_location
    @should_update_location ||= record && (record.current_login_ip != record.current_login_ip_was)
  end
end
```

Then, from my controller, I could call `user_session.should_update_location?` and perform some logic.

The issue however, is that (as far as I can tell from testing) all the callbacks are *copied* across into the `User` model, so that if you create a user model then the before_create defined above in UserSession is also executed. This happens *even if you are not creating a UserSession*. That means that my `@should_update_location` was called twice (once when the user was created, once when the session was created) but by the time the session was created, the `current_login_ip` had been set, so my `should_update_location?` returned false.

I could work around it by simply calling out to my method from within the UserSession itself like this:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  before_create :update_location_if_new_or_changed

  private

  def update_location_if_new_or_changed
    if record && (!record.persisted? || (record.current_login_ip != record.current_login_ip_was))
      puts "calling set_update_location"
    end
  end
end
```

But that doesn't seem any nicer. So I have currently given up, and implemented the `after_save` hook on User.

What is the right way to perform this sort of "if the current_login_ip changes" behaviour?  Is it OK, in this instance, to actually have a callback on the User model? It's currently looking the nicest way to me.